# Firebase C++ SDK - Windows 10 - Build Error

Tags: c++, windows, firebase, sdk

I m getting a build error while trying to build Firebase C++ SDK on Windows 10

Firebase C++ SDK Version : 11.4.0(Latest)

Platform : Windows 10

CMake : 3.27.4

Below is the error message while building using CMake

```
CMake Error at desktop_build/external/src/firestore/cmake/firebase_utils.cmake:87 (message):
  firebase_execute_process(): command failed with non-zero exit code 1:
  C:/Program Files/CMake/bin/cmake.exe --build .  -- (working directory:
  E:/Program
  Files/Firebase/firebase-cpp-sdk-11.4.0/desktop_build/external/src/firestore-build/external)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  desktop_build/external/src/firestore/cmake/external_rules.cmake:61 (firebase_execute_process)
  desktop_build/external/src/firestore/CMakeLists.txt:118 (download_external_sources)
```

I got the source code from :

`git clone https://github.com/firebase/firebase-cpp-sdk.git`

Followed the instructions given in README.md of:

`https://github.com/firebase/firebase-cpp-sdk`

Commands used for the building :

```
mkdir desktop_build && cd desktop_build
cmake -G “Visual Studio 16 2019” ..
```

I have both 2019 and 2022 versions of VS Community installed

Tried with Firebase C++ SDK Version - 11.3.0 as well and getting the same error

Not able to recognise the root cause of the error.

Comment: The problem could be caused by the space in the path. If you are  using `git clone https://github.com/firebase/firebase-cpp-sdk.git` why is the source at `E:/Program
  Files/Firebase/firebase-cpp-sdk-11.4.0`

Comment: @drescherjm - Same error occurs where ever I keep the source code and build it.
I m confused if having both VS2019 and VS2022 installed is causing the issue.

Comment: ***I m confused if having both VS2019 and VS2022 installed is causing the issue*** I say it's unlikely. At work I have 5 or 6 compilers installed and have almost never had an issue related to that over the 15 years that I have used CMake for most of my projects as a software engineer in medical imaging research. I don't use firebase however I would assume it behaves like most projects that use CMake.

Comment: Same error and also having both VS2019 and VS2022